# How about a badge for high quality content?

Tags: feature-request, answers, badges

Since the purpose of badges seems to be encouraging certain behaviours and rewarding positive contributions to the site, would it be a good idea to make some badges for posting consistently good content?

For example, I currently have about 45k rep over 1165 posts, so averaging about 40 points per post.  It's not too shabby but nothing to write home about.

But now look at the user [e-satis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9951/e-satis) for example, 170k rep over 682 posts - a whopping 250 points per contribution.  And if you look at this user's posts, they are **very well written and generally exceptionally high quality content** of great use to many people!

The rep score itself doesn't say much about the quality of a user's content because it is so much affected by the quantity of contributions.  A user can accrue massive rep just from basically answering help vampires in the current system.  How about a badge to remind us to aim for quality, not quantity?

Not sure exactly how to calculate it robustly but I was thinking of something like a bronze/silver/gold for users who have at some stage reached a median upvotes-per-post exceeding 3/5/10 (just pulled those numbers out of thin air) and only available after a minimum number of posts.

Open to suggestions for the badge names.

Comment: There's already Nice/Good/Great Question/Answer

Comment: And he has lots of gold badges for them.

Comment: Yes but it is quite a different thing to have some good posts as opposed to consistently good posts.

Comment: Without some solid idea on how to quantify and measure quality there is no point suggesting this. Note that up votes are not a foolproof indicator of quality.

Comment: "A user can accrue massive rep just from basically answering help vampires in the current system." A few individuals come to mind, and at least one of them has an average of *< 10 points per answer*.

Answer (score 14):

A badge for posting consistently good content is a good idea. There's a [series of badges for consistently asking good questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234259/asking-days-badges). The problem with your proposal is that it does not really capture consistently good answerers.

You propose rewarding users who have a high median score on their posts. This incentivizes posting high-score answers, which reputation and the single-answer badges (Nice Answer, etc.) already do. This also incentivizes *not* posting low-score answers. This is problematic because it rewards skipping questions that aren't likely to attract a lot of votes on answers, including:

- questions in low-voting tags;
- difficult questions that only a few experts understand;
- already-answered questions where the current answers are not good.

I'm pretty sure that the best strategy to get a high-median badge is to concentrate on high-voting tags and get a lot of [FGITW](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) answers. We don't need more hastily-written, just-scraping-the-surface answers.

In addition, if deleted answers aren't taken into account, this would be an incentive for heavy self-vandalism — deleting any answer below the threshold even if it was helping people.

I'm all for rewarding high-quality content, but reputation *should* already do that. To fix the discrepancy between reputation and quality, I'd rather find ways for score to correlate better with quality.

Comment: All good points.  Do you have any ideas for ways to make score correlate better with quality?  Currently we have to check in the users profile and do the division mentally .. or dig around in data explorer a bit ..